# WPF - Style behavior - Global style that disappear

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, mergeddictionaries

**strong text**I have a style defined into a MergedDictionary (see below). It does add cursor style to all splitter bar in my app. It works perfectly... Until...

The problem is that style disappear suddenly. I have an ActiPro DockSite with document that include other 3rd party controls. When I add a document to my dockSite, the style disappear.

I tried:

1. Clean App.Resources.MergedDictionaries
2. Fill App.Resources.MergedDictionaries with new set of ResourceDictionary
3. Reapply window template with mainWindow.ApplyTemplate();

But without success. The style does not want to reappear. It is stuck somewhere in the darkness of the microsoft style application behavior, I don't really know. But one thing for sure, my MergedDictionary is still alive and there but does not want to show its face.

It could come from anywhere. But how can I find the offending code and how could I fix that ?
Anybody can help me !!! I'm desperate.
Thanks !

> **Update 2013-09-30**. I snooped and add results at the bottom. But I found something very interesting, after doing some mouse interaction, the style came back. In fact I think it never disappeared. The only problem is probably a behavior from other manufacturer which should do a mouse capture or something similar which would overwrite my default mouse style. I will do more investigation.

```
<Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridSplitter">

                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Rectangle>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ResizeDirection" Value="Columns">
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeNS"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ResizeDirection" Value="Rows">
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Snoop results before:

[image]

Snoop results after (which appears the same to me):

[image]

Comment: 2 things , first try to add to your style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridSplitter}}" , 
Secondly , snoop go to Style Property and delve to it's source , 
let me know what you come up with for further help .

Comment: I can't add BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridSplitter}}". It says that a loop is detected. I didn't think about snoop for that. I will give a try this morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer. The problem is not a style that disappear but a code 18. The problem was at 18 inches (arounf 50 cm) from the screen... ME !!!

I changed Mouse.OverrideCursor to Hourglass while loading a DockingDocument but set back the OverrideMouse to Mouses.Arrow instead of null.

Thanks to Eran for its support. Snooping it told me that the style was still there and make me search somewhere else.